# Report subscription error code 612794256-627738 (-836958080)

Tags: email, reporting, error

I have received this error code **612794256-627738 (-836958080)** in some reports subscriptions email.

I have searched this error code in salesforce documentation and I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know the meaning of that error code? Is there any page where I can found some information about this type of error codes?

Thank you all!

Comment: Based on Salesforce backend logs for the stacktrace id (-836958080), the error thrown is `common.exception.RateLimitingException: ConcurrentUiRequests Limit exceeded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a GACK, so an unhandled exception in the Salesforce platform, you could read this [post about them](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack):

The first number, the one with a hyphen in it, is the ID for that specific event, while the second one, the one in parentheses, is the hash (an ID) of the stack trace.

Only Salesforce Support can help you, so you should open a case about it providing any useful information you have, i.e. stating the steps to reproduce the error.
Once the error has been logged into the bug tracking system, they could provide you with a Reference ID that can be used on [Known Issues](https://issues.salesforce.com/) page.